# Does $K_0$ of a regular (affine) scheme always surjects onto $K_0$ of any open subscheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a Noetherian separated regular scheme and let $U$ be an open subscheme. Then does there always exist an exact sequence $K_0(X)\to K_0(U)\to 0$ ? If not, then is it at least true when $X=\text{Spec}(R)$ is affine ? And what is a good reference for this ?

(Here, $K_0(-)$ denotes the Grothendieck group of the exact category of Algebraic vector bundles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited) This is true for Noetherian seperated schemes, since surjectivity holds for $G_0$, and $K_0=G_0$. Since for any open $U$ in $X$ Noetherian, and $\mathcal F$ a coherent sheaf on $U$, there exists a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F'$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal F'|_U\cong \mathcal F$.

This is exercise $II,5.15$ in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: I doubt only being able to lift a coherent sheaf on $U$ to a coherent sheaf on $X$ is enough ... the lift of a vector bundle on $U$ to a sheaf on $X$ might no longer be a vector bundle on $X$ ...

Comment: Of-course if $X$ is a Noetherian separated regular scheme, then so is any open subscheme of $X$ and we know that for Noetherian separated regular schemes, $G_0\cong K_0$, so you're good in that case ...

Comment: My mistake, I edited my answer.